# To create 5000-10000 vph in a freeway in SUMO simulation

Tags: xml, sumo

I am trying to generate heavy traffic on the freeway using netedit. But somehow i find the traffic to be very low while running in simulation. Is there any threshold for traffic generation. Kindly let me know if there any other way

```
<routes>
    <flow id="flow_0" begin="0.00" from="e10" to="e03" end="3600.00" number="8000"/>
</routes>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to adapt the departure parameters especially add `departSpeed="max" departPos="last" departLane="best"` to your flow definition. There is also an [FAQ](https://sumo.dlr.de/docs/FAQ.html#how_do_i_get_high_flowsvehicle_densities) on that.